Unable to log into my wordpress backend due to "Parse error: syntax error, any suggestions on how to fix this?
When trying to login to my wordpress backend (primarily working in elementor, with a few other plugins too), I get the error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ';' in /var/www/techsavvy.academy/public_html/wp-content/languages/}continents-cities-da_DK.l10n.php on line 2
I am not familiar with this error, nor am I used to programming, but my programmer is on summer holidays and I am desperate.
Do you have any suggestions on how I can fix it myself?
Best,
Amalie
I haven't tried anything, as I am a designer (with limited python and javascript experience) and therefore have no idea where to begin.

Hello and welcome on Stack Overflow, that error can be caused my multiple reason but if the path u've pasted (which contains an extra } but that might be just a copy-past issue) actually exists then you should open that file with some good IDE for PHP (try Visual Studio Code which is free) and it should point you to the missing character. The other thing i can say is that its weird to have a php file inside the languages folder of wp-content

Hi Diego,
Thank you so much for your reply.  As you can tell I am limited in my knowledge (however have VS code already, so far so good) How do I find and download the file in question? My guess is I have to find it somewhere when I inspect the page, but I can't seem to figure out where.
Furthermore, when I have fixed it - how do I reupload?

Your best bet is to obtain FTP access and use some FTP client like filezilla to connect to the server that hosts the files and then you can download, edit and reupload the file. This would be the "easy and quick fix route" but keep in mind that your programmer may have setup more complex infrastructure to publish file in production which i cannot be aware of.

Thank you so much, seems like I might have to give my programmer a call during his vacation.

If he tells you how to access the server and how to publish the file in there you may already have good chances of pulling it off alone. Good luck

This file is auto generated from WordPress. You can export the file going to this link https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/6.3.x/cc/da/default/ and at the bottom you will see export button but first select the type of file you want to export and in your case select PHP .l10n.php then go to the directory and replace it. You will need access to the server using FTP or other way.

Thank you so much Snuffy!
I got a hold of him and he fixed it in no time. I'll ask him for some basic knowledge about how to fix things like this to avoid this kind of trouble in the future.
Thank you so much for your responses!
